# How to open a Julia repl in a specific mode

Tags: julia

I want to have a short script that opens a Julia REPL in a specific mode, for instance, the `shell>` mode or the `C++ >` (from Cxx.jl) mode. How can this be achieved?

**Update**:
After getting an answer I created a script to start Julia REPL in Cxx.jl C++ mode (and pre-run some C++ code). See it here: https://github.com/cdsousa/cxxrepl.jl.

Comment: Could be worthwhile to open an issue for a command-line option to determine the startup mode.

Comment: Issue opened: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/23910

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whatever this may be good for...

The easiest way (without having dug into the innards of `Base.REPL`) is to write the appropriate character to `STDIN`, e.g

```
write(STDIN.buffer,'?');
```

If you want to start the REPL and drop to shell mode immediately, call julia as

```
julia -i -e write(STDIN.buffer,';')
```